# Changing LDAP password from CLI

Tags: 14.04, ldap

First of all, I'm a beginner with LDAP. I use it on my workstation to emulate a production environment for web application I'm working on. So I'm not logged through LDAP and the users there are different than the real users on the workstation.

I have set up LDAP using the standard procedure (`dpkg-reconfigure`). I also setup phphLDAPadmin and I can login as `admin` or as a regular user and change is password (as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VN6KdYHVDs)).

However, I haven't succeeded in changing the password from command-line. I have tried different options for `ldappasswd` but can't figure out the correct combination.

For the sake of the example, let's imagine that:

- we want to change the login of user `cronaldo` (which is different than my current login)
- users are in the `People` ou
- the domain `test.institute.fr`

Can someone provide a working example? It would be great to be prompted for password instead of having to write them on the CLI.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and OpenLDAP 2.4.31 (from repositories).

Comment: Does cronaldo immediately drop to the floor clutching his leg when given a challenging command to run?

Comment: No he usually tries to avoid contact ;). And I usually try to google and ask colleagues before ;)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I find it and it was not that hard (I got lost with SASL stuff that are not relevant). The command is:

```
ldappasswd -H ldap://localhost -D 'cn=Cristiano Ronaldo,ou=People,dc=test,dc=institute,dc=fr' -W 'cn=Cristiano Ronaldo,ou=People,dc=test,dc=institute,dc=fr' -S`
```

where:

- `-D` is used to specify the binding user
- `-W` is used to prompt password for the binding user
- `-S` is used to prompt the new password

One trick was to use the `cn` (`Cristiano Ronaldo`) and not the `uid` (`cronaldo`). Note that you will be asked first for the new password twice and then for the current password.